# Loop not populating list properly

Tags: apex

I am trying to build out a list that returns the users associated to a manager. The user I’m passing in is a manager with 8 active direct reports.  I’ve validated that the if statement evaluates to true, I’ve validated that there are 8 users being added to the list in the map and that I can access the list with a get statement with the managers id as the argument. It's only returning the userid I'm passing into the method.

I know I'm missing something but I'm just not seeing it. Hoping there are some good suggestions out there.

```
public class HierarchyUtil {
    Public Map<Id,List<Id>> mgrIdRepListMap = new Map<Id,List<Id>>();
    public List<Id> repMgrIds = new List<Id>();
    public hierarchyUtil() {
        List < User > regUsers = [SELECT id, Continent__c, UserRoleid, UserRole.Name, ManagerIdFROM USER WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND UserType = 'Standard' AND UserRole.Name LIKE 'EU%'];
        List < Id > userGroup = null;
        for (User u: regUsers) {
            if (mgrIdRepListMap.get(u.ManagerId) != NULL) {
                userGroup = mgrIdRepListMap.get(u.ManagerId);
                userGroup.add(u.id);
                mgrIdRepListMap.put(u.Managerid, userGroup);
            } else {
                userGroup = new List < Id > ();
                userGroup.add(u.id);
                mgrIdRepListMap.put(u.ManagerId, userGroup);
            }
        }
    }
    public void createHierarchy(Id repId) {
        repMgrIds.add(repId);
        for (Id u: repMgrIds) {
            generateHierarchy(u);
        }
    }
    //repId = logged in user id
    public List < Id > generateHierarchy(Id repId) {
        for (Id s: mgrIdRepListMap.get(repId)) {
            if (mgrIdRepListMap.get(s) != null) {
                (repId).size();
                x++) {
                repMgrIds.addall(mgrIdRepListMap.get(s));
            } else continue;
        }
        return repMgrIds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you recheck last method `generateHierarchy` of your post if it has any typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core problem is that you are applying too many steps in the processing and there is a mistake somewhere in there.

This simpler logic does what I think you want:

```
public class UserHierarchy {

    private Map<Id, List<Id>> m = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    public UserHierarchy() {
        for (User u : [
                SELECT Id, Name, Continent__c, UserRoleid, UserRole.Name, ManagerId
                FROM USER
                WHERE IsActive = TRUE
                AND UserType = 'Standard'
                AND UserRole.Name LIKE 'EU%'
                ORDER BY Name
                ]) {
            List<Id> l = m.get(u.ManagerId);
            if (l == null) {
                l = new List<Id>();
                m.put(u.ManagerId, l);
            }
            l.add(u);
        }
    }

    public List<Id> getReports(Id managerId) {
        List<Id> l = m.get(managerId);
        return l != null ? l.clone() : new List<Id>();
    }

    public Set<Id> getManagers() {
         return m.keySet().clone();
    }
}
```

(The `clone` calls are only needed if you want to guard against the calling code modifying the collections; in most cases I wouldn't include them.)

**PS**

Just noticed this is largely the same as MSCB's answer so +1 to that answer.

Comment: Thank you - this helped. 
The issue now is that sometimes the passed over doesn't have any direct reports and sometimes there are multiple layers that need to be added to the list. In other words - a director and his management reports as well as the the managers reports as well. Any thoughts about navigating multiple layers of users?

Comment: @iKnowledge On the multiple layers, you can either make use of the ability to query up to 5 levels of parent (`OR` together a bunch of e.g. `Manager.Manager.ManagerId = :id` terms in the where clause and include the same terms in the fields you return) to minimise the number of queries or loop starting from the top manager, then using the report ids and then their report's ids and so on. I've written it both ways.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to incorporate that in my code. The code could pass in the id of a rep that has no reports, a manager, director or vp level. The results returned should be only for the id passed in and their reports if any.   I'm just having a mental block with this. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

This code may help your scenario. I thing createHierarchy method dummy method in this Class.

```
public class HierarchyUtil {

    public Map<Id,Set<Id>> mgrIdRepListMap = new Map<Id,Set<Id>>(); // Initialze the Map

    public hierarchyUtil() {    // In this method from Manager Id and set of User Ids 

        // Query and put the map value
        for (User u: [SELECT Id, Continent__c, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, ManagerId FROM User WHERE ManagerId != null AND IsActive = TRUE AND UserType = 'Standard' AND UserRole.Name LIKE 'EU%']) {

            if(!mgrIdRepListMap.containsKey(u.ManagerId))    // Check whether manager Id contains in the map key value 
                mgrIdRepListMap.put(u.ManagerId, new Set<Id>());   // If does not contains map key to add the map and intialize a set of Id   

            mgrIdRepListMap.get(u.ManagerId).add(u.Id);    // If contains map key get the user Id set add add the new user Id
        }
    }

    // I thing this method doesn't use in this scenario, because the login user Id is a single Id 
    // You directly call the generateHierarchy method with the parameter of user Id.

    public void createHierarchy(Id repId) {
        if(repId != null) {
            generateHierarchy(repId);
        }
    }


    public Set<Id> generateHierarchy(Id repId) {

        if(repId != null && mgrIdRepListMap.contaisKey(repId)) {    // Check whether the map contains repId
            return mgrIdRepListMap.get(repId);    // If contains Key to get the Set of userId and return it
        }

        return null;    // Otherwise return null
    }
}
```